# Upload (small) file to sharepoint folder using MS GraphAPI. Documentation obsolete

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to upload small file to sharepoint folder. I found sample in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-updating-an-existing-file).
Unfortunatelly, provided sample is not syntactically correct - could not be compiled! Probably, documentation was not updated to reflect latest (v3) changes.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

byte[] stream = Base64.getDecoder().decode("The contents of the file goes here.");
graphClient.me().drive().items("{item-id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .put(stream);
```

method `put()` does not accept `stream` any more. It accept only `DriveItem`, but I could not find a way to initialized it with stream...

```
@Nullable
public DriveItem put(@Nonnull final DriveItem newDriveItem) throws ClientException {
    return (DriveItem)this.send(HttpMethod.PUT, newDriveItem);
}
```

**Could anybody provide working example?** And/Or list to current (functional) documentation... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that correct way is wit adding `.content()` after `.items()`

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

byte[] stream = Base64.getDecoder().decode("The contents of the file goes here.");
    graphClient.me().drive().items("{item-id}")
    .content()
    .buildRequest()
    .put(_stream_);
```